# Determine the $n$-th power of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine the $n$-th power of the matrix. $$\pmatrix{2 & 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \\1 & 2 & 1  \\ }$$ May you help me with the answer since the book states :  $${1\over 6}\pmatrix{4+2\cdot4^n & 3\cdot4^n & -4+4^n \\ -2+2\cdot4^n& 3\cdot4^n & 2+4^n\\-2+2\cdot4^n &  3\cdot4^n & 2+4^n  \\ }$$ while mine misses the ${1\over 6}$. So who is right?
$$$$Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Comment: Neither.${}{}{}$

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B2%2C2%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C2%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C2%2C1%7D%7D%5En) agrees with your math book, though it includes some $0^n$ terms so that the formula is also right when $n=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Check with $n=0$ and $n=1$. Both are wrong.

Comment: (albeit the problem with the book's solution is only for $n=0$; the check for $n=1$ is OK. Hence, if one of the two solutions has to be correct, go with the book's one; and doublecheck whether the exercise says something about '$n\geq 1$')

Comment: The solution for $n=0$ for the book is entirely right - what you've missed is that there's a zero eigenvalue in the matrix, so you're effectively getting $0^0$, and I'm guessing the book's solution leaves that as $0$.

Comment: Notice that, if you multiply the solution for $n=0$ by the original matrix, you get the original matrix back again.

Comment: ? Any matrix brought to the power $0$ should be the identity matrix. Here, the book gives
$${1\over 6}\pmatrix{6 & 3 & 0 \\ 0& 3 & 3\\0 &  3 & 3  \\ }$$

Comment: that's not true, any more than $0^0=1$. Do you expect the zero matrix raised to the power $0$ to produce the identity matrix?

Comment: $${1\over 6}\pmatrix{6 & 3 & -3 \\ 0& 3 & 3\\0 &  3 & 3  \\ }\pmatrix{2&2&0\\1&2&1\\1&2&1} = \pmatrix{2&2&0\\1&2&1\\1&2&1}$$

Comment: Also, notice that you made a mistake in evaluating the book's result at $n=0$.

Comment: @GlenO: yes, I do. By convention (used by every single book and teacher I have had), and also to be consistent with the fact that $0^0$ could be seen as the limit of $e^{x\ln x}$.

(yes, I just noticed the upper-right term was wrong)

Comment: I'm sorry, Clement, but $0^0$ is an undefined form, just like $\frac00$ and $0\cdot\infty$.

Comment: I reckon it depends on the choice you make. Yet, I stand my ground ;)
https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~alopez-o/math-faq/mathtext/node14.html

Comment: @ Glen O When you talk about the $0-th$ power of the matrix it works right with the multiplication, but a matrix raised to the power $0$ isn't by definition the identity matrix? Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a little complicated. It is often taken, by convention, that the zeroth power of a matrix is always the identity. But that approach is not always suitable. The literal translation of the result obtained here is that the resulting matrix is the limit as $n\to0$. As a result, non-zero eigenvalues are taken to 1, while any zero eigenvalue remains zero. The Wolframalpha solution is probably best, as it allows use of the user's definition of $0^0$ - if you take it, in this case, to be the limit of $0^n$ (and thus $0$), then it's zero. If $0^0=1$, you'll get the identity matrix.

Comment: @Glen O I am sorry for asking again, but when I inputting $n=0$ into the book's answer, how then does the identity come in?

Comment: "non-zero eigenvalues are taken to 1" but then isn't it create dependent eigenvectors?

Comment: @Glen O I'm very grateful for your help!

Comment: @proofy: sorry, I was asleep at the time you asked those questions. The identity doesn't come from the book's answer, and that's the point that Clement was making. To get the identity, you need some extra terms of the form $0^n$ - which, for $n>0$, is necessarily zero.

Comment: @Glen O Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 1):

I get for the symbolic form depending on *n* and the symbolic eigenvalues $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ (where we insert later the known values $\small \alpha=0,\beta=1,\gamma=4$)
$$ A^n = \frac16 \small \begin{array} {|r|r|r|r}
 4 \cdot \beta^n+2\cdot\gamma^n & -3\cdot\alpha^n+3\cdot\gamma^n & -4\cdot\beta^n+3\cdot\alpha^n+\gamma^n & \\
 -2\cdot\beta^n+2\cdot\gamma^n & 3\cdot\alpha^n+3\cdot\gamma^n & 2\cdot\beta^n-3\cdot\alpha^n+\gamma^n \\
 -2\cdot\beta^n+2\cdot\gamma^n & -3\cdot\alpha^n+3\cdot\gamma^n & 2\cdot\beta^n+3\cdot\alpha^n+\gamma^n
 \end{array}
$$
and replacing with the actual values for $\small \alpha,\beta,\gamma$ we get
$$ A^n = \frac16 \small \begin{array} {|r|r|r|r}
 4 +2\cdot 4^n & -3\cdot 0^n+3\cdot 4^n & -4 +3\cdot 0^n+4^n & \\
 -2+2\cdot 4^n & 3\cdot 0^n+3\cdot 4^n & 2-3\cdot 0^n+4^n \\
 -2+2\cdot 4^n & -3\cdot 0^n+3\cdot 4^n & 2+3\cdot 0^n+4^n
 \end{array}
$$

**For $n \in \mathbb N \text{ and } n \gt 0$** this reduces to
$$ A^n = \frac16 \small \begin{array} {|r|r|r|r}
 4 +2\cdot 4^n & 3\cdot 4^n & -4+4^n & \\
 -2+2\cdot 4^n & 3\cdot 4^n & 2+4^n \\
 -2+2\cdot 4^n & 3\cdot 4^n & 2+4^n
 \end{array}
$$
$ \qquad \qquad $ which matches the solution of the book.

**For $n=0$** this gives with $0^0=1$ 
$$ A^0 = \frac16 \small \begin{array} {|r|r|r|r}
 4 +2 & -3+3 & -4 +3+1 & \\
 -2+2 & 3+3 & 2-3+1 \\
 -2+2 & -3+3 & 2+3+1
 \end{array} = \frac16 \small \begin{array} {|r|r|r|r}
 6 & 0 & 0 & \\
 0 & 6 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 6
 \end{array} = I
$$
*(So the textbook-solution should be commented with the required $0^0$-definition)*

---

*I used the diagonalization-procedure of Pari/GP for this and to get a textform for this answer:*

```
M = [2,2,0;1,2,1;1,2,1]
tmpM=mateigen(M)
tmpW=tmpM^-1
tmpD=tmpW*M*tmpM
MPow = tmpM*matdiagonal(['a,'b,'c])*tmpW 
\\ on text-level we have later to replace a by \alpha^n and so on
```

Comment: "the symbolic form depending on n and the symbolic eigenvalues α,β,γ" - it is genius and, I'm unfortunately unfamiliar with- is there an explanation for some general case with nxn matrices? Truly grateful!!!

Comment: I mean is there a systematic way to connect,as simply as that, between eigenvalues and the original matrix to the n-th power?

Comment: @proofy: Hmm, I don't really understand your question, maybe because I'm a bit tired just now. The original matrix is (if it is diagonalizable at all) always $A=M \cdot D \cdot M^{-1} $ where *D* is diagonal and contains the eigenvalues in the diagonal. Then powers of *A* are simply $A^p=M \cdot D^p \cdot M^{-1}$ and $D^p$ is simply, that the scalar elements on the diagonal are raised to the *p* 'th power... But possibly you meant another thing?

Comment: @proofy: Also, one should possibly mention L. Euler from whom I've learned the true importance of the method "to generalize as much as possible" before to try to arrive at a specific solution... which gives the idea to generalize the eigenvalues and keep them as symbolic entities first.

Comment: Thank you very much again! I was performing the technical calculations without any second thought of the "big picture". It was enlightened.

Comment: Nice and full doc.++

Answer (score 1):

I think about  $$\pmatrix{\left(2^{2n-1}-\frac{2}{3}(4^n-1)\right) & 2^{2n-1} & \frac{2}{3}(4^n-1) \\ \left(2^{2n-1}-\frac{2}{3}(4^n-1)+1\right) & 2^{2n-1} & \frac{2}{3}(4^n-1)+1 \\\left(2^{2n-1}-\frac{2}{3}(4^n-1)+1\right) & 2^{2n-1} & \frac{2}{3}(4^n-1)+1  \\ }$$

Comment: +1 Nice, Babak! I miss you! Where've you been? ;-)

Comment: @Babak S. It is a graceful one, thank you very much!

Comment: @Babak S. Maybe it would be better if you replace $4^n$ by  $2^{2(n-1)}$? Also if at the first column you put parentheses around $ \frac{2}{3}(4^n-1)+1$?

Comment: @Babak S.:░⋘Excellent⋙░✓

Comment: @flashdesign2550: $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try Jordan normal form of your matrix.